# Unable to display Vertica tables from Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, vertica

I am new to Spark and I am trying to make a connection from Spark 1.6.3 to Vertica 8.1.1. I'm using the following code provided by Vertica to query:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("vertica-spark-connector-testing").setMaster("local[1]")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val host = "x.x.x.x"
val db = "db"
val table = "table"
val user = "user"
val password = "password"
val part = "12";
val opt = Map("host" -> host, "table" -> table, "db" -> db, "numPartitions" -> part, "user" -> user, "password" -> password)
val df = sqlContext.read.format ("com.vertica.spark.datasource.DefaultSource")
.options(opt).load()
val c = df.select("a").filter("a > 5").count
println(c)
sc.stop();
```

I'm encountering the following error

> scala> val c = df.select("a").filter("a > 5").count :42:
>   error: value select is not a member of
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader
>            val c = df.select("a").filter("a > 5").count

And when I try to show the tables, it is not returning anything

```
scala> sqlContext.sql("show tables").show()

+---------+-----------+
|tableName|isTemporary|
+---------+-----------+
+---------+-----------+
```

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong and any help on how I can connect would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connection to Vertica is working otherwise you would get an exception on the "show tables" query.

Check the permissions assigned to your codemonkey user.  Do they have access to custDim?

Check the structure of custDim.  Does it have a column "a"?

Comment out your val c line and put df.show() above it and try again.  This will at least tell you what columns are contained in your data frame.

Comment: Thanks for the response Dave. df.show() gives me a similar error.         error: value show is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader

Comment: If sqlContext.sql("show tables").show() works for you try sqlContext.sql("select * from table").show()

Comment: Have you tried sqlContext.read.format("jdbc") instead? Also in your val opt=Map I think table might be dbtable.  Your code looks similar to https://my.vertica.com/get-started-vertica/integrating-apache-spark/.  It sounds like your SPARK_HOME is set correctly otherwise nothing would work.  Double-check ls $SPARK_HOME/jars/ver* for the vertica driver

Comment: Thanks for your input Dave. The following was parsed into two different lines by Spark which is why the data frame val df never got created.                                 
val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.vertica.spark.datasource.DefaultSource")
.options(opt).load()                                                                                                 That's why the error was occurring. I moved them into a single line and it got fixed. I am able to show the table with df.show() now. Thanks again!